# Errno(0) when attempting log in with OO statement

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I am attempting to make a more secure log in system. My registration is working fine so its not a connection issue. Just needing a fresh pair of eyes to see if there are any errors that I may be missing, can anyone help please? Thanks!

login.php

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

        $user = $_POST['username'];    
        $pass = $_POST['password'];


        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $user)){
            echo "Bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
        }
        $userdata = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $userdata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $stmt->bind_result($user, $pass);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if(password_verify($pass, $row['password'])){

            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $_POST['username'];
            header('Location: profile.php');
            exit();
        }

    }
else{
    echo "Login Failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

index.php(The login form)

```
<div id="loginform">

    Log in details<br /><br />

    <form method="post" action="login.php">

        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <br /><br>
        Password:
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <br /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

 </div>
```

Comment: so is `Errno(0)` meant to mean that you get the error message from `echo "Bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;`? and if so, what is the actual error message?

Comment: What is your question? My fresh pair of eyes doesn't see anything obviously wrong. Are you getting an error? From which call?

Comment: 'Login Failed: ()' Sorry Not 0! Doesnt give me any more information on the error

Comment: The script runs and loads. Just when submit is pressed the page refreshes, and posts the message 'Login Failed: ()'

Comment: Why are you using both `bind_result` and `fetch_array` to get the results?

Comment: `'Login Failed: ()'` is in the `else {...}` of `if (isset($_POST['submit']))  {...}`. So you need to look at why your `$_POST['sumbit']` is not set. Try adding a `print_r($_POST);` or `var_dump($_POST);`. Is your form submitting the standard/traditional way, and not through ajax?

Comment: I know, I deleted my comment.

Comment: I am submitting it the traditional way!

Comment: I have have used the print_r($_POST); and it is showing the $_POST when I add it before the mysqli->prepare. Does this mean my error is within the statements??

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code accurately? Maybe that line is in the `else` for the `password_verify` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$stmt->errno` and `$stmt->error` in the `Login Failed` error message. That line is in the `else` clause for `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`, so it has nothing to do with a MySQL error. I'm not sure why you're ever getting that message, since it should only happen if you go to `login.php` without submitting the login form on `index.php`.

Since you're using `$userdata->fetch_array()` to fetch the row of results from the database, you shouldn't also use `$stmt->bind_result()` -- do one or the other. I don't think `bind_result()` is doing anything, since you never call `$stmt->fetch()` to get a row into those variables.

If you decide to go with `bind_result()`, you need to use a different variable for the password, because `$pass` contains the password submitted from the form.

You need to check whether a row was returned by the query -- if the user enters an invalid username, it will not. So the password check should be:

```
if ($row && password_verify($pass, $row['password']) {
    ...
}
```

You should then have an `else` clause for this that reports that the username or password was invalid. You should not distinguish whether it was the username or password that was wrong, this would be bad for security (it helps a brute-forcer to know that he guessed the username correctly, and just needs to try different passwords).

`$stmt->close()` should be inside the `if` block.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance appreciate it.

Comment: Good job on this Barmar, *bravo*